# Cannot convert value of type 'ServiceModel.Type' to expected argument type 'ServiceModel'

Tags: swift, xcode, mongodb, swiftui, realm

```
struct ServicePageView: View {
    @ObservedRealmObject var employeeGroup: ServiceModel
    
    Section(header: Text("Select Employees: ")){
                List{
                    ForEach(employeeGroup.employeesList, id: \.self){ employee in
                        Text(employee.firstName)
                     }
                }
            }

}

struct ServicePageView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ServicePageView(employeeGroup: ServiceModel)
    }
}
```

Hello,

Getting an error "Cannot convert value of type 'ServiceModel.Type' to expected argument type 'ServiceModel'" at the ServicePagePreview(employeeGroup: ServiceModel). Am I using the wrong data type?

Comment: You're just trying to pass the type `ServiceModel`. You need to actually pass an instance of it. I'm not really familiar with the Realm stuff, so there may be more needed, but at the least, you'd need `ServiceModel()`

Comment: There's a bit of ambiguity here, the error states `ServicePagePreview(employeeGroup: ServiceModel)` note the `ServicePagePreview` part - and there's nothing in your code referencing a `ServicePagePreview` object or function - your code references `ServicePageView` and `ServicePageView_Previews`. I think you're looking at the wrong section of code.

Answer (score 0):

You are supplying the type here:
ServicePageView(employeeGroup: ServiceModel)

I think you meant to give an instance as in ServiceModel()
which would be an init returning an instance of the type.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your code in a "body" to be a view, like this:

```
struct ServicePageView: View {
    @ObservedRealmObject var employeeGroup: ServiceModel

    var body: some View {  // <--- here
       ...
    }
}
```